# Complex representation, Young tableaux

Tags: group-theory

So let's evaluate the $8 \bigotimes 8$ in $SU(3)$. The result we get is

[image]

My doubt is about the $\overline{10}$ representation. How do we know it is the complex representation? I mean, we know that $\overline{3}$ is represented by

[image]

I have no problem about that, but how do we identify $\overline{10}$? Is it because we have $a$ above $b$?